# Image Resize Filter not working with WYSIWYG + CKeditor?

Tags: 7, media, wysiwyg

I have installed image resize filter, set it to be active on the 'full editor' content editing mode which is where I have CKEditor activated.  CKEditor is working great, the problem is that I don't see any image resizing functionality.

I have insert installed as well. I can upload a file, and when I hit insert it goes into the CKeditor as the original size.

I added an images field to Basic Page which got the upload button/insert showing up and that's working great, but I see no sign of Image Resize Filter in action anywhere :?

Answer (score 1):

For re-sizing of images instead of using [Image Resize filter](https://drupal.org/project/image_resize_filter) you colud use the feature of drupal 7 itself ie by setting up an File Type for your image.

You could set up a File type you should go to Configuration -> Media -> File types -> Manage Display

There are basically 6 types of image file type that you could use

1. Link
2. Default
3. Preview
4. Large
5. Original
6. Small

These are the default file type that you can select and are there with there default values so we could override the default values by our own values and could use that file type for uploading our own images of particular size.